# Windows 10 VPN ipv6 subject

Tags: vpn, ipv6, browsing

I installed a vpn client that enabled a vpn adapter. It works great, however IPv6 is not being routed, so when I go to sites that give my address is giving the origin and not the vpn server.

So... at the end is not securing or maskering my geografic location.

Is there anyway to solve this, because, it makes no much sense the use of VPN for geografical reasons if server easyly may detect original address. Example using this site to check address: [IPv6 checker](https://test-ipv6.com/)

I have checked the security section and disabled in all addapter setting the ipv6 checkbox. However keep showing the address.
I also, set the registry entry to disabled ipv6 globally. Restarted computer, and is the same
Any Ideas?

Comment: Does the VPN service support IPv6? It sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: @music2myear according what I have read most VPNn do not.
That is why in other threads they just recommend to disable ipv6.
Maybe I will open another queestion related to this subject.
Thanks

Comment: Your location is not based on your PCs IP address, but by the public IP address of your connection. VPN changes your public IP, more or less. Can you disable IPv6 on your modem's upstream port?